# How to fix the multiple value assignment to the variables in the python code below?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Given a list of unique numbers in python, I need to swap the positions of the maximum and minimum numbers in the list.**

*Apart from the traditional way of doing by getting the positions of the numbers by for loop, I tried to do that by the in-built python functions and used it directly in the multiple variables assignment method which is shown below.*

```
a = [i for i in range(6, 1, -1)]
print("The original array is =", a)  # print's [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]

index_max = a.index(max(a))
index_min = a.index(min(a))

# a[ a.index(max(a)) ], a[ a.index(min(a)) ] = min(a), max(a)  #print's [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
a[index_max], a[index_min] = min(a), max(a)  # print's [2, 5, 4, 3, 6]

print("The swapped array is =", a)
```

> Line no.7 doesn't work as it gives the output [6, 5, 4, 3, 2], instead
>   of [2, 5, 4, 3, 6].
>
> Whereas line no.8 works perfectly!!

Comment: curious. `a[ a.index(max(a)) ], a[ a.index(min(a)) ] = 4, 10` results in `[4, 5, 4, 3, 10]` but `a[ a.index(max(a)) ], a[ a.index(min(a)) ] = 2, 6` results in `[6, 5, 4, 3, 2]`

Comment: Please refer to the answer of @Enzo below and then come back here.

When the biggest element is replaced by the smallest element at the position **a[0]** then `a.index(min(a))` takes the position of the first occurrence of the smallest element which is a[0].

Let's say our array is `a1=[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` instead of `a2=[6, 5, 4, 3, 2]` then a1[ a.index(max(a1)) ] will be replaced by 2 and when `a1.index(min(a1))` searches for the min element it returns the position of the first occurence which is 0 so a1[0] gets replaced by max(a1).

Answer (score 2):

According to docummentation of Python:

> WARNING: Although the definition of assignment implies 
>   that overlaps between the left-hand side and the right-
>   hand side are `safe' (e.g., "a, b = b, a" swaps two
>   variables), overlaps within the collection of assigned-to 
>   variables are not safe! For instance, the following program 
>   prints "[0, 2]":
>
> ```
> x = [0, 1]
> i = 0
> i, x[i] = 1, 2
> print x
> ```

So the problem is that, in line 7, Python first does

```
a [a.index(max(a))] = min(a)
```

Now, `a = [2, 5, 4, 3, 2]`. After that, Python does

```
a [a.index(min(a))] = max(a)
```

But `min(a) = 2`, and `a.index(2)` returns 0. So, in the end, `a = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]`. That's why assign the index of min and max before swap the variables does work.

**Reference:**
https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/assignment.html

---

**Edit:** reference to Python 3 as suggested by @chepner:

> Although the definition of assignment implies that overlaps between
>   the left-hand side and the right-hand side are ‘simultaneous’ (for
>   example a, b = b, a swaps two variables), overlaps within the
>   collection of assigned-to variables occur left-to-right, sometimes
>   resulting in confusion. For instance, the following program prints [0,
>   2]:
>
> ```
> x = [0, 1]
> i = 0
> i, x[i] = 1, 2   # i is updated, then x[i] is updated
> print(x)
> ```

**Reference:**
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

Comment: That's a *really* old link; the equivalent for Python 3 should be provided.

Comment: See the end of [section 7.2](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

Comment: so if you really wanted to confuse the next programmer you could do `index_max, index_min, a[index_max], a[index_min] = a.index(max(a)), a.index(min(a)), min(a), max(a)`

Comment: Thanks, Enzo and @chepner

Answer (score 1):

The important here is the order of the operations. When you do:

```
a[ a.index(max(a)) ], a[ a.index(min(a)) ] = min(a), max(a)
```

Python do things in that order:

- `max(a)` # >> 6
- `a.index(max(a))` # >> 0
- `a[...] = min(a)` # >> a[0] = 2

Then, it do the same with the second member:

- `min(a)` # >> 2
- `a.index(min(a))` # >> 0
- `a[...] = max(a)` # >> a[0] = 6

The bad behaviour is natural, since you changed the index during the operation...

Comment: aren't these operations supposed to take place simultaneously?

Comment: @KshitijAgarwal No. It's basically the same as `t = (min(a), max(a)); a[a.index(max(a))] = t[0]; a[a.index(min(a))] = t[1]`. The right-hand side of `=` is evaluated left-to-right, then the assignments from the right-hand side occur from left-to-right.

Comment: One more question is the precedence rule followed by all programming languages?